# My linear mixed effects model violates the assumption of homoscedasticity! How do I account for this in my model?

Tags: r, lme4-nlme

I am running a model that looks like so:

```
TD_PE_analysis1 <- lmer(PE ~  learn_prof * trial * condition + (1|subject) + (1|image), data=td_pref_all)
```

Where `PE` is prediction error, `learn_prof` is a between subjects fixed effect (two groups), and `trial` and `condition` are within subject.  The data appear below:

```
structure(list(subject = c("61086f515114c26363323a17", "6090919e35432ed7cf716ca4", 
"5dc797a6a4cc4255f8ea588e", "5f9b014daee4da2af5391e54", "5f2226ed22f0956bf55ddb71", 
"5dcc1eb66f3f168a9515c150", "5ac8f79068b65b00018d7ef9", "CC_86", 
"610455c1ee6fdb0b18a4bcf2", "5e363f622dd2885f05d43978", "62a21304a03b371374d3bea2", 
"5f3c48bea714e02094c9d0ae", "6282571cf39cd89341a474e9", "610881055b4f5daa95c3118c", 
"5f2853a8e736e613955f73bf", "5d3fc2a0bb27940001db4067", "60ae256eb7d66c5f70d02814", 
"5f70c532da8e516a8ccca1da", "5ac8f79068b65b00018d7ef9", "5f9e40344dbd1f3ea731975d"
), age = c(19L, 22L, 22L, 21L, 18L, 22L, 21L, 18L, 20L, 20L, 
21L, 20L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 21L), sex = c(2L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L), race = c("4", "5", "5", "4", "5", "5", "2", "5", 
"4", "5", "2", "2", "6", "5", "5", "5", "5", "5", "2", "5"), 
    bapq = c(3.97222222, 3.861111111, 3.666666667, 3.444444444, 
    2.444444444, 2.888888889, 2.444444444, 2.47222222, 3.055555556, 
    3.194444444, 3.777777778, 3.944444444, 3.38888889, 3.75, 
    4.027777778, 3.111111111, 3.305555556, 3.5, 2.444444444, 
    3.277777778), event = c(75L, 80L, 50L, 23L, 103L, 57L, 25L, 
    12L, 48L, 63L, 32L, 77L, 63L, 40L, 115L, 96L, 15L, 47L, 88L, 
    67L), timestamp = c("7/1/22 14:47", "6/7/21 15:27", "11/16/20 22:42", 
    "6/7/21 15:21", "6/7/21 15:38", "11/24/20 14:22", "6/7/21 13:49", 
    "9/3/20 18:40", "7/1/22 14:33", "11/16/20 19:11", "6/30/22 20:03", 
    "11/16/20 18:58", "7/1/22 14:53", "7/1/22 16:31", "6/7/21 15:27", 
    "6/7/21 15:31", "6/7/21 15:14", "7/1/22 13:25", "6/7/21 14:00", 
    "11/16/20 20:25"), condition = c("odd", "odd", "mean", "odd", 
    "mean", "odd", "mean", "odd", "mean", "odd", "odd", "odd", 
    "mean", "odd", "odd", "odd", "odd", "mean", "odd", "mean"
    ), rating = c(3, 2, 4, 6, 4, 3, 6, 3, 1, 4, 4, 3, 4, 4, 2, 
    5, 3, 4, 6, 5), rt_ms = c(1446, 2414, 1106, 2371, 3292, 1076, 
    4996, 2328, 2215, 1345, 1399, 1710, 1562, 1847, 1881, 2009, 
    1894, 1810, 3336, 1329), image = c("radio_1", "bagel_2", 
    "chocolate5", "pie1", "kiwi_01", "beads_2", "drums_1", "bacon_01", 
    "chess_2", "candy_3", "muffin3", "piano_2", "bike_01", "camera_1", 
    "berries_01", "grilled_cheese_01", "notebook_3", "cookie4", 
    "ball_02", "drums_1"), trial = c(14L, 19L, 49L, 22L, 42L, 
    56L, 24L, 11L, 47L, 2L, 31L, 16L, 2L, 39L, 54L, 35L, 14L, 
    46L, 27L, 6L), onset_s = c(660.204, 682.005, 369.298, 185.31, 
    966.195, 459.121, 204.844, 97.076, 378.956, 566, 228.529, 
    703.03, 684.207, 298.489, 838.409, 796.401, 111.799, 366.679, 
    844.903, 745.011), profile_rating = c(3L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
    5L, 5L, 2L, 4L, 6L, 1L, 4L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 6L, 4L, 3L
    ), block = c(2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
    2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), sub_num = c(94L, 29L, 
    129L, 37L, 42L, 174L, 5L, 25L, 87L, 21L, 56L, 7L, 96L, 109L, 
    26L, 36L, 25L, 70L, 5L, 111L), own_pref = c(2L, 5L, 2L, 6L, 
    5L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 5L, 2L, 
    4L), item_num = c(128L, 18L, 49L, 123L, 93L, 17L, 69L, 9L, 
    53L, 38L, 102L, 97L, 28L, 46L, 25L, 82L, 111L, 61L, 20L, 
    57L), cat1 = c(1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 1L), cat2 = c(2L, 11L, 12L, 
    12L, 10L, 1L, 2L, 9L, 4L, 12L, 12L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 10L, 11L, 
    1L, 12L, 3L, 2L), profile_rating_new = c(2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 
    2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 3L, 
    2L), PE = c(1, 1, 2, 5, 2, 0, 3, 1, 2, 0, 3, 0, 2, 2, 0, 
    2, 0, 0, 3, 3), PE_si = c(1, -1, 2, 5, 2, 0, 3, 1, -2, 0, 
    3, 0, 2, 2, 0, 2, 0, 0, 3, 3), pro_PE = c(0L, 2L, 0L, 5L, 
    3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    2L), mean_p1 = c(3.065789474, 4.197368421, 4.266447368, 3.914473684, 
    4.233552632, 3.006578947, 3.75, 4.213815789, 3.5, 4.404605263, 
    4.296052632, 4.4375, 4.240131579, 4.164473684, 4.398026316, 
    4.430921053, 2.927631579, 4.891089109, 3.713815789, 3.75), 
    mean_p2 = c(2.783950617, 3.878787879, 4.185185185, 3.771428571, 
    3.950617284, 2.691358025, 3.771604938, 4.484848485, 3.580246914, 
    4.475308642, 4.484848485, 3.757575758, 4.135802469, 3.666666667, 
    4.136363636, 4.057142857, 2.971428571, 4.777777778, 3.818181818, 
    3.771604938), mean_p3 = c(2.989399293, 3.703180212, 4.498233216, 
    3.858657244, 3.459363958, 3.261484099, 3.692579505, 4.689045936, 
    3.568904594, 4.971731449, 4.469964664, 3.989399293, 4.169611307, 
    3.971731449, 3.922261484, 4.243816254, 3.409893993, 5.148409894, 
    3.561837456, 3.692579505), med_p = c(3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 4, 
    4, 4, 5, 4.5, 5, 4, 4, 5, 5, 3, 5, 4, 4), own_pref_NaN = c(2, 
    5, 2, 6, 5, 2, 4, 4, 1, 1, 5, 4, 5, 4, 3, 3, 2, 5, 2, 4), 
    learn_prof = c(2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
    1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L), learn_prof1 = c("asd", 
    "asd", "td", "asd", "asd", "td", "asd", "td", "asd", "td", 
    "asd", "td", "asd", "asd", "asd", "asd", "asd", "asd", "asd", 
    "td")), row.names = c(12463L, 17892L, 3289L, 16538L, 14597L, 
3377L, 12537L, 489L, 20682L, 3998L, 22643L, 8497L, 12141L, 20915L, 
14658L, 12907L, 18807L, 15890L, 12494L, 10977L), class = "data.frame")
```

Of course there are significantly more trials and participants in my real dataset. `learn_prof` consists of two groups and I went to compare their variance of residuals as recommended by the link [here](https://ademos.people.uic.edu/Chapter18.html) and found the two groups residual variances were significantly different. I have tried running the model below to account for this:

```
TD_PE_analysis1 <- lmer(PE ~  learn_prof * trial * condition + (1|subject) + (1|image), data=td_pref_all, weights = varIdent(form = ~1 | learn_prof))
```

However, I find myself running into this error even after attempting to remove NAs in the large dataset

> Error in model.frame.default(data = td_pref_all, weights = varIdent(form = ~1 |  :
> variable lengths differ (found for '(weights)')

I'm unsure if I am implementing this function correctly. I also want to confirm whether I am on the right track with even confirming homoscedasticity. Has anyone run into these issues?

Comment: Per your other question you seem to have found out through Levene's test that your 2 groups are indeed heterogeneous re: variance; however, you got this particular error because lmer doesn't support the use of "varIdent" function, not because of anything in your data.

Comment: Interesting, is there an equivalent for lmer? I mostly found suggestions related to varIdent

Comment: Your previous question describes the outcome as ratings and in the sample data PE takes values from 0 to 5. This suggest the outcome is an ordinal variable and to consider ordinal logistic regression instead. It could elegantly solve your homoscedasticity issues since ordinal regression makes no such assumption.

Comment: So, you can use varIdent within nlme package lme function. In my understanding, it doesn't work within lmer. However, like others have suggested, I'm not sure you need to remedy the heterogeneity like this, if at all.